# Matching a specific unknown multiple times using regex in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Example buffer:

```
Line 1 is my favourite line
Line 2 is bad
Line 3 is bad
Line 1 is still my favourite line
```

How do I use regex to match the 2 sentences that contain "Line 1" ?

Please note that the number '1' is not known to me, Only thing that's known is that the multiple occurences have the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $s = q{Line 1 is my favourite line
Line 2 is bad
Line 3 is bad
Line 1 is still my favourite line
};

my ($l1, undef, $l2) = $s =~ /(Line \s* ([0-9]+) .*) [\w\W]*? (Line \s* \2 .*)/x;
print "$l1\n$l2\n";
```

output

```
Line 1 is my favourite line
Line 1 is still my favourite line
```

Comment: Hello mpapec, could you elaborate a little as I don't have the exact same usecase and will need to understand what you've done to implement it.

Comment: @Proteen it looks for two lines with same number (note `\2` which is reference to `([0-9]+)`). If you need something more complex, regex is probably not right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
use 5.14.0; #including features 'say' and smart match (~~)
use warnings;


my @lines = (); #lines that occurred

while (<DATA>){
    my $line = /^(Line\s*+\d+\b)/ ? $1 : ''; #\b to avoid '2' matches '22'
    $line ~~  @lines and do {say "$line occurred before."; next;}; 
    push @lines, $line;
}


__DATA__
Line 1 is my favourite line
Line 2 is bad
Line 3 is bad
Line 1 is still my favourite line
Line 22 is bad
```

Output:

```
Smartmatch is experimental at ./tst.pl line 16.
Line 1 occurred before.
```

Whilst the above code is good to pick up line numbers that have occurred, it doesn't tell you what those lines are. If you do want that feature, then try the following code:

```
my @lines = ();

while (<DATA>){
    my $line = /^(Line\s*+\d+\b)/ ? $1 : ''; #\b to avoid '2' matches '22'
    next unless $line;
    push @lines, $_;
    my @occurred = grep {/$line/} @lines;
    @occurred > 1 and print for @occurred;
}
```

Output:

```
Line 1 is my favourite line
Line 1 is still my favourite line
```